# Invoke a serie of actions when Enter key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings, actionevent

I have one *Swing* project and I have an action listener on `JTextField` for <kbd>Tab</kbd> key as follows.

There is a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` inside the action listener. And when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed option pane will show an Information message.

My problem is that, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on OK button of Information Message dialog, a serie of action is invoked viz <kbd>Tab</kbd> action of `JTextField` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> action of `btnNewButton`.

If I use mouse click on OK button of Error Message dialog, every thing is fine and no problem.

Can I solve this using key bindings instead of key listener?

Please suggest a solution

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private JDialog dialog;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
                Collections.emptySet());
        textField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, " Please Press ENTER Key", "information",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    btnNewButton.grabFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        textField.setBounds(73, 28, 178, 28);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, " That Invoked New Button Also", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(223, 137, 117, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Please Press TAB Key");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(83, 55, 183, 15);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can I solve this using key bindings instead of key listener?"* Well, .. yes you might, but my first thought was a `DocumentListener`. **General tips:** 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  ..

Comment: .. using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @Andrew I have Edited the code and is reproducible now. Please suggest me necessary modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding method `keyReleased()`. The `JOptionPane` is closing before the `keyReleased()` method is called and since you make `btnNewButton` the focused component after the `JOptionPane` is closed, the `keyReleased()` method is invoked – which displays the other `JOptionPane`.

Simply rename the method to `keyPressed()`.

Also, you don't need the `dialog` member. The first parameter to `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` should be the `JFrame`.

Here is your code with my corrections.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnNewButton;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
                Collections.emptySet());
        textField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Test.this, " Please Press ENTER Key", "information",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    btnNewButton.grabFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        textField.setBounds(73, 28, 178, 28);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Test.this, " That Invoked New Button Also", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(223, 137, 117, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Please Press TAB Key");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(83, 55, 183, 15);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

Note that (at least in JDK 15) there is no need to explicitly set the default close operation for `JFrame` since the default **is** EXIT_ON_CLOSE